# windows phone 7 apps marketplace paid to free

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketing

I have question about paid and free + ad-based apps/games in wp7 marketplace, can I publish my app as paid version initially and later(after a month or so) can i publish the same app/game as free + ad based version? Is there any such rule/policy in wp7 marketplace.
I could not find proper answer on the net not lucky enough. And i hope this is not off topic question.  - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. In the settings for your app you get to set the price and "Free" is one of the options.

Some things to consider before doing it:

- It may be better to have a free and a paid version available to increase visibility.
- When switching from paid to free, or vice-versa, you won't get put the the top of the new apps list.
- The new list may not be such a big concern given that there are hundreds of new apps a day meaning this list is of little value. Some people may however be regularly checking new apps in a particular category.